# How to keep both Mapping=arabicdigits and Ligatures=TeX in this MWE?

Tags: biblatex, ligatures, arabic, right-to-left, mapping

Please consider the MWE below:

**MWE - scenario 1**

```
\documentclass[demo]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[locale=mashriq,numerals=mashriq,abjadjimnotail=true]{arabic}
% \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Ligatures=TeX,Mapping=arabicdigits]{Simplified Arabic}
% \setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Ligatures=TeX,Mapping=arabicdigits]{Simplified Arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Mapping=arabicdigits,Ligatures=TeX]{Simplified Arabic}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Mapping=arabicdigits,Ligatures=TeX]{Simplified Arabic}

\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  references = {المراجع}}
\makeatletter
\def\abx@comma{\ifdim\lastkern>\z@\unkern\fi\abx@puncthook{،}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ibnsina,
    author = {{ابن سينا}},
    year = {{١٤١٧}},
    title = {السماع الطبيعى من كتاب الشفاء},
    publisher = {دار المناهل},
    location = {لبنان، بيروت}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

هنا نص بالعربية مع ارقام هندي ١، ٢، ٣، الخ ومع الواصلة، واحدة - واثنتان -- وثلاثة ---.

احد المراجع\parencite{ibnsina}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**Output -- scenario1**
[image]

**MWE -- scenario2**

```
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Ligatures=TeX,Mapping=arabicdigits]{Simplified Arabic}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Ligatures=TeX,Mapping=arabicdigits]{Simplified Arabic}
% \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Mapping=arabicdigits,Ligatures=TeX]{Simplified Arabic}
% \setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Mapping=arabicdigits,Ligatures=TeX]{Simplified Arabic}
```

**Output -- scenario2**
[image]

I get either of these two effects depending on which argument is passed at the end of the Arabic font definitions. In scenario 1 last argument is `Ligatures=TeX`, whereas in scenario 2 the last argument is `Mapping=arabicdigits`.

**Question**
Is there any way to keep both Hindi numbers and the TeX ligatures of en dash and em dash effects at the same time?

**Notes**

- compiled by xetex
- `\textemdash`, `\textendash` are obvious answers but I don't want to resort to them in Rt-to-Lt document as it will produce messy text script
- undesired output is marked with yellow in the screenshots

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use only one mapping file at a time; so the solution is to merge the map files.

Prepare a file `texarabicdigits.map` containing

```
; TECkit mapping for TeX input conventions <-> Unicode characters

LHSName "TeX-text"
RHSName "UNICODE"

pass(Unicode)

; ligatures from Knuth's original CMR fonts
U+002D U+002D           <>  U+2013  ; -- -> en dash
U+002D U+002D U+002D    <>  U+2014  ; --- -> em dash

U+0027          <>  U+2019  ; ' -> right single quote
U+0027 U+0027   <>  U+201D  ; '' -> right double quote
U+0022           >  U+201D  ; " -> right double quote

U+0060          <>  U+2018  ; ` -> left single quote
U+0060 U+0060   <>  U+201C  ; `` -> left double quote

U+0021 U+0060   <>  U+00A1  ; !` -> inverted exclam
U+003F U+0060   <>  U+00BF  ; ?` -> inverted question

; additions supported in T1 encoding
U+002C U+002C   <>  U+201E  ; ,, -> DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
U+003C U+003C   <>  U+00AB  ; << -> LEFT POINTING GUILLEMET
U+003E U+003E   <>  U+00BB  ; >> -> RIGHT POINTING GUILLEMET

; from arabicdigits.map
U+0030 <> U+0660 ;
U+0031 <> U+0661 ;
U+0032 <> U+0662 ;
U+0033 <> U+0663 ;
U+0034 <> U+0664 ;
U+0035 <> U+0665 ;
U+0036 <> U+0666 ;
U+0037 <> U+0667 ;
U+0038 <> U+0668 ;
U+0039 <> U+0669 ;
```

Now run

```
teckit_compile texarabicdigits
```

which will produce a file `texarabicdigits.tec`. Keep it in the same directory as your main file. Now the following test file

```
\documentclass[demo]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[locale=mashriq,numerals=mashriq,abjadjimnotail=true]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Mapping=texarabicdigits]{Scheherazade}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Mapping=texarabicdigits]{Scheherazade}

\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  references = {المراجع}}
\makeatletter
\def\abx@comma{\ifdim\lastkern>\z@\unkern\fi\abx@puncthook{،}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ibnsina,
    author = {{ابن سينا}},
    year = {{١٤١٧}},
    title = {السماع الطبيعى من كتاب الشفاء},
    publisher = {دار المناهل},
    location = {لبنان، بيروت}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

هنا نص بالعربية مع ارقام هندي ١، ٢، ٣، الخ ومع الواصلة، واحدة - واثنتان -- وثلاثة ---.

احد المراجع\parencite{ibnsina}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

will produce the following output

[image]

The `.tec` and `.map` file can then be moved in a local TeX tree.